# what package to use when generating Google api key

Tags: android, google-api, maps

What package must i use when generating apikey when my project has more than one package. All the packages have the same name space. Eg com.example.views,com.example.adapters

Comment: If you find the response correct please accept the response.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the application package name. The application package name is written even at the beginning of your app manifest. In this case should be com.example

Comment: Ok that is what i have been doing but still i can't seem to get my map to show all i see is a gray greed....

Comment: Check you have selected Google Maps API v2 in the developer console because there is Google Maps also but the Android version is different. I spent a week on this things. In addition, you have to check your app permissions. See here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#install_and_configure_the_google_play_services_sdk

Comment: Other tips: if you are using com.example I think could be a problem try to change in this way: right-click on project->Android Tools->Rename Application Package. In addition be sure to use your production certificate fingerprint not the debug one.

Answer (score 1):

you should use the package name as the project name you created at the creation of your project ex:- com.example.barcodescanner  where barcodescanner is my project name